# Checking existence of file in same folder

Tags: php

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.
I want to include a php file but I need to check if it exists first and every time I run it, I get a failure message. I can see the file is there from my FTP application.

```
        <?
            $man_file="/site/67/blog/612.php";
            if (file_exists($man_file)){
                include($man_file);
            }
            else
            {
                echo $man_file;
            }
            clearstatcache();
        ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What failure message are you getting?

Comment: _failure message_ you say?

Comment: Your real script starts with <?php, right?

Comment: Try using `<?php` instead of the short code `<?` `<?php` will always work the short code may not if that parameter is not turned on

Comment: "612.php" That's what I asked it to show if file exists returns false but the file is there in the same folder.

Comment: Using <?php makes no difference. I've just tired it,

Comment: It would seem more logical to `clearstatcache()` before attempting a file access. But I doubt thats the reason for the error

Comment: That makes no difference either.

Comment: is the file extension lowercase? Linux is case sensitive, I've seen files with if it's Linux and the extension is uppercase it will fail

Comment: Yes. Exactly as shown.

Comment: Can you change the error message to `echo 'Missing ' . $man_file;` just in case you coded the same thing in the included file.

Comment: It's not in the file because I tried including the file before the test which worked but I need to test it's existance.

Comment: Permissions? Is then next logical choice.  was it uploaded by root and now you run it under a different user?

Comment: Take the guesswork out of things: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Add a `echo getcwd();` just to prove PHP is looking in the directory you think it is

Comment: and "how" are you accessing that file, as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? Two different animals here. *"I get a failure message"* - Being what exactly? Again; error reporting and tell us what you get back.

Comment: I isn't looking for it in the directory I thought it was but addind the full path doesn't seem to work either. Check the edited question.

Comment: `$man_file="/site/67/blog/612.php";` use a full server path `$man_file="/var/usr/public/site/67/blog/612.php";` or a relative one. You have been asked what error you get back, the "real" one and on more than one occasion. I can't keep guessing what that is; "file not found"? Other?

Comment: check for allow_url_fopen = 1 on php.ini file

Comment: That did it Fred. I've never had to do that before. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @RichardYoung I posted my comment as an answer below to mark the question as solved. Glad this one got solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That did it Fred. I've never had to do that before. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote it and accept it. – Richard Young*

Posting my comment as "the" answer:

`$man_file="/site/67/blog/612.php";`

Use a full server path (an example):

```
$man_file="/var/usr/public/site/67/blog/612.php";
```

or a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path to the file as well. So try something like

```
$man_file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/612.php";
```

If the directory you are searching is the `root`.

Comment: I tried including the path. I tried the full path it tired putting "./" before it but nothing made any difference.